# What is the VBA/Selenium coding in order to turn off 'remote debugging' so I can open Edge in 'Internet Explorer Mode'?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I can open an instance of Edge in excel using VBA coding:

```
Dim obj as New WebDriver
                                                                
obj.Start "edge"
                                                                  
obj.Get "http://..."
```

But Edge opens with the "Turn off remote debugging" notification bar under the website address.  In order for my macro to manipulate Edge I need to it to be in Internet Explorer Mode, but the remote debugging being enabled is preventing this.  The website address I am directing my code to is designated to open in the Internet Explorer Mode but when I use VBA to open it I get the 'remote debugging' message.  What is the coding to turn the 'remote debugging' mode off so Edge opens in the Internet Explorer Mode as intended. Please help and thank you!

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for following-up.  I am new at this so it takes me a while to process help.  Literally in the time between your post and now I have been delving into Python with selenium edgedriver and IEdriver to replicate the macro code that operated in IE11.  Give me another day or so, so I can respond to your post in a concise and as clear manner as possible how I am doing, since I am learning as I go.  =)  Again I appreciate the follow-up.

Comment: Is there any update about the issue? You can come back anytime when you finish doing test.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off remote debugging. The right and only way to automate IE mode in Edge is using IE Driver. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp) for detailed information about how to do this.

Besides, I suggest you to use other programming languages such as C#, Python, Java to automate Edge IE mode. I think you're using SeleniumBasic in VBA which is too old to automate IE mode. It doesn't contain the key `InternetExplorerOptions` object. If you want to use IEDriver to automate IE mode in Edge, you need to use IEDriver version 4.0.0.0 or greater, which is not available in SeleniumBasic.